# Impedir continuar programa cuando se produce una excepcion

Tags: c#, excel

Tengo este metodo, que abre un archivo excel, lo que intento es que cuando la ruta no sea correcta no pueda continuar el programa hasta que la conexion sea correcta.

```
    private void Conectar()
            {
                try
                {
                    sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(tbxRuta.Text);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Fallo al abrir el archivo...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                }

            }
```

¿Que seria conveniente para realizar el programa correctamente?

Answer (score 1):

El método debería devolver información indicando si la operación ha tenido éxito o no para que la lógica del programa pueda tomar la decisión de si debe continuar o no.

Algo así:

```
private bool Conectar(){
  try{
    sheet = excel.Workbooks.Open(tbxRuta.Text);
    return true;
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Fallo al abrir el archivo...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

De esta forma en la lógica del programa podrías comprobar si el archivo se ha abierto correctamente o no:

```
if (Conectar()){
   // Continuar con el programa
}
```

Answer (score 1):

También puedes verificar la ruta antes de llamar al método, por ejemplo:

```
if (File.Exists(tbxRuta.text))
{
    // llamas al método 
}
else
{
    // avisas al usuario que el archivo no existe
}
```

Aun así, podría darse el caso que el archivo no se abra por x razones, ya sería otra validación si quieres hacerla.